# track them down vs track them

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language, phrasal-verbs

> "They laid mines and he had to track all of them so he doesn't step on
> one of them."
>
> "They laid mines and he had to track all of them down so he doesn't
> step on one of them."

Does track them down imply that he's going after the mines, while track them implies he's just memorizing the locations of the mines?

Comment: If he's memorizing the positions, then he has to **keep track** of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably would not use either “track” or “track down” here. The first dictionary I looked up confirms my intuition: track means “follow the course or trail of,” so I would not normally use it to describe something immobile like landmines.  I would say something like find, discover, map, locate or reveal instead.

Comment: "He had to (past tense)... so that he _didn't_ step on one."

Comment: @KateBunting Had to detect the mines? Find? Discern? Watch out for? Avoid?

Comment: _Locate_ would be my suggestion.